# Обозначение района на карте?

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi

Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли с помощь api карт через геокодер найти район, например "район Сокольники" и выделить его на карте не точкой, а границами района?

Comment: нет такой функции. тебе нужно сначала добавить скрытые полигоны вручную а потом при поиске проверять в какой полигон входит указанная точка и делать этот полигон видимым. Посмтори, как в примерах реализовано. Не поленись просмотреть все примеры

Comment: Что значит скрытые полигоны? Координаты всех точек полигона мне откуда получить, к примеру всех районов Москвы. Как я понимаю яндекс в ответе не дает этих данных?

Comment: В ответе API Яндекс.Карт нет такой информации. Можно выгружать административные границы с любых сторонних сервисов, например, http://data.esosedi.org , затем отображать их инструментами JS API на карте.

Comment: полигон - это одна из фигур яндекс карты. У нее есть свойства. Одно из свойств всех фигур - `visible`. Координаты точек границ полигона (района) ищи в открытых источниках или вытаскивай сам. Яндекс-карты тебе просто предоставляют инструмент, а данные - уже твоя забота. Плюс есть  коллекция геообъектов, у которой есть хэлперы, в том числе метод определения, входит ли точка в геообъект